# how to click button load gridview but disload page web

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem with ASPxGridView.
I have a aspxgridview1 contain button.
aspxgridview2 contain data.
when I pressed the button. data will be displayed on the aspgridview2 corresponding  "ID" of aspxgridview1 but without reloading the page.
this is following aspxgridview1

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" KeyFieldName="Province_Id">
            <Columns>
                <dx:GridViewCommandColumn VisibleIndex="0">
                    <EditButton Visible="True">
                    </EditButton>
                    <ClearFilterButton Visible="True">
                    </ClearFilterButton>
                    <CustomButtons>
                        <dx:GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton ID="show" Text="show">
                        </dx:GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton>
                    </CustomButtons>
                </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Province_Id" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="1">
                    <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Name" VisibleIndex="2">
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataButtonEditColumn VisibleIndex="4">
                </dx:GridViewDataButtonEditColumn>
            </Columns>
            <SettingsBehavior AllowFocusedRow="True" />
            <Settings ShowFilterRow="True" ShowFooter="True" ShowGroupPanel="True" ShowTitlePanel="True" />
        </dx:ASPxGridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TravelConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Province] WHERE [Province_Id] = @Province_Id" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Province] ([Name]) VALUES (@Name)" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Province]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Province] SET [Name] = @Name WHERE [Province_Id] = @Province_Id">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Province_Id" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Province_Id" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're set on using the `ASPxGridView`s, the best you can do is wrap both controls in `UpdatePanel`s. If you don't like that solution, you'll need to look into using ajax to get the data after clicking a button.

Comment: Thanks you, I known this solotion. do you have any other ideas?

Comment: The only other option would be to load all of the possible data when the page loads, then use javascript to switch the data displayed in the grid. Whether that is a good idea depends on your specific usage. You wouldn't be using the `ASPxGridView`s in that case either.